# Automapper Guid to string mapping fails with NullReferenceException if used with Queryable Extensions

Tags: automapper

I'm having a problem with one of my mappings that I can't seem to resolve. 
Here is the model:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the class I'm mapping to:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping and the test:

```
public class AutomapperTest
{
    public AutomapperTest()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, conf => conf.MapFrom(p => p.Id))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ClientCode, conf => conf.MapFrom(p => p.Client.Code)));
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MappingTest()
    {
        Client client = new Client { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Code = "CTS" };
        Order order = new Order { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Client = client };
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order> { order };

        List<OrderDto> list = orders.AsQueryable().Project().To<OrderDto>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Test fails with a NullReferenceException on an attempt to project the list of OrderDto objects. Here is the exception, which comes from Automapper:

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, Type typeOut) in QueryableExtensions.cs: line 50
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, Type typeOut) in QueryableExtensions.cs: line 136
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass1`2.<CreateMapExpression>b__0(TypePair tp) in QueryableExtensions.cs: line 24
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.DictionaryFactoryOverride.ConcurrentDictionaryImpl`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) in ConcurrentDictionaryFactory.cs: line 37
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine) in QueryableExtensions.cs: line 21
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression`1.To() in QueryableExtensions.cs: line 251
   at AutoMapperIssue.AutomapperTest.MappingTest() in Class1.cs: line 47
```

Mapping works just fine if Queryable Extension is not used:

```
List<OrderDto> dtos = Mapper.Map<List<Order>, List<OrderDto>>(orders);
```

Am I missing something?

Just an update:
I'm using it with NHibernate, getting identical exception.

```
var fromDb = Session.Query<Order>().Project().To<OrderDto>().ToList();
```

Seems like it chokes on Guid to string conversion. If i comment the Id field out, it works fine for both NHibernate and collection.AsQueryable().

```
private static LambdaExpression CreateMapExpression(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, Type typeIn, Type typeOut)
{
    var typeMap = mappingEngine.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(typeIn, typeOut);
    ...
    foreach (var propertyMap in typeMap.GetPropertyMaps().Where(pm => pm.CanResolveValue()))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

it fails on foreach since typeMap is null. typeIn = System.Guid   typeOut = System.String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a legit limitation. Here is the author's [explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/automapper-users/4yGbUHKeSy0/yY5SLxqN67AJ)

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.1.1 need to reference both dlls:

AutoMapper and AitoMapper.Net4

In version 3.2.1 still an issue

Comment: Both dlls are referenced. It maps OK without Queryable Extension, but fails to map Guid to string if Queryable Extension is used.